# How do I start two inline Threads with a lock in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an application which has to process XML files by adding metadata from a remote database. Since I'm opening and parsing them in Java, I thought threading might improve the performance (by processing the document while my application waits for the response from DB).

Let's say I have two methods:

```
HashMap result = getMetadata(String id);
Document doc = loadDocument(String path);
```

I would like to start both simultaneously and wait for both to finish. Can I do this inline?

Regards,
Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to start both simultaneously and wait for both to finish. Can I do this inline?

You can start two Threads and use `join()` to wait for them to finish.

If you want to get the results of two tasks, you can use an ExecutorService and give it a Callable.  Later, you can `future.get()` the results in the current thread when they are finished.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        HashMap result = getMetadata(String id);
    }
}


Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        Document doc = loadDocument(String path);
    }
}

t1.start();
t2.start();

t1.join();
t2.join();
```

Comment: This is generally how to do it, but something tells me you will not want to assign the result to a local variable inside the `run()` method. It shouldn't be a problem to assign it to a variable declared outside the thread though.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [java.util.concurrency.ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).

See the sample below:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

Future<HashMap> resultFuture = executorService.submit(new Callable<HashMap>() {
    public HashMap call() throws Exception {
        return getMetadata(id);
    }
});

Future<Document> docFuture = executorService.submit(new Callable<Document>() {
    public Document call() throws Exception {
        return loadDocument(path);
    }
});

try {
    HashMap result = resultFuture.get();
    Document doc = docFuture.get();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // handle
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    // handle
} finally {
    executorService.shutdownNow();
}
```

Comment: Jup. Pretty much what I did right after Peters post. Googled "future promise" up :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at general producer-consumer type solutions.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps using the annonymous Runnable Interface  .. as in

```
Runnable runResult  = new Runnable{
public void run{
//do stuff here related to getMetadata
}
    Thread resultThread = new Thread(runResult);
            resultThread.start();
}

Runnable runLoadDoc = new Runnable{
public void run{
//do stuff here related to loadDocument
}
    Thread docThread = new Thread(runLoadDoc);
            runLoadDoc.start();
}

//Logic for a join.. so that it will wait for both threads to complete..
```

Not sure if this is what u need..